# Can Z output from rasterize_terrain() be made numeric?

Tags: lidr

I'm updating code to compute height *and* elevation of tree tops derived from `locate_trees()`. To do this I also create a DTM from the LAS file. The older `grid_terrain()` produced a RasterLayer and the current `rasterize_terrain()` produces a SpatRaster.

When adding `locate_trees()` output with the SpatRaster DTM, at first (can't recreate it now) I was getting a 'non-numeric argument to binary operator ERROR'; ...and with the code below, the elevation is simply dropped. I think this is because the Z output from `rasterize_terrain()` is a chr and num from `locate_trees()`.

This is solved by converting the DTM from SpatRaster to a RasterLayer. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to make the rasterize_terrain() Z value compatible with the locate_trees()?

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
# get tree top height & tree top elevation
# --------------------------------------------------------
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(lidR)
library(lidRplugins)

# read the LAS and normalize
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Topography.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
nlas <- normalize_height(las, tin())
writeLAS(nlas, paste0(tempdir(), "/nlas.las"))

# create dtm - values extracted will be added to tree top height so that it can be visible in 3D software
dtm <- rasterize_terrain(las, 0.5, tin()) # update from grid_terrain
(spVals <- str(values(dtm)))

dtm <- as(dtm, "Raster") # convert SpatRaster to RasterLayer
(rlVals <- str(values(dtm)))

# create a catalogue out of the one LAS file for input to catalog_map
nlasCat <- readLAScatalog(paste0(tempdir(), "/nlas.las"))

# function to locate trees and to add the elevation to the tree height
ttopFun = function(las) {
  ttops <- locate_trees(las, lmfauto(hmin = 1))
  Zdtm <- extract(dtm, ttops)
  ttops$E <- ttops$Z + Zdtm
  return(ttops)
}

nlasCat@output_options$drivers$sf$extension <- ".gpkg" # maybe use shp.
opt_output_files(nlasCat) <- paste0(tempdir(), "/ttops_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}")
output <- catalog_map(nlasCat, ttopFun)

# look at the attributes
gpkgFile <- st_read(output)
head(gpkgFile)
# --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Your code is working (no error) and looks ok.

Comment: It is only working because I convert the SpatRaster to a RasterLayer.  I was thinking that the function should work directly with the SpatRaster output

Comment: I tested without the conversion. No error.

Comment: Btw I changed `lmfauto` to `lmf`. Don't know if it matters

Comment: No, I don't think `lmf` matters.  So, if you comment out the `dtm <- as(dtm, "Raster")`, it works for you? I'm still getting the warning `In clean_columns(as.data.frame(obj), factorsAsCharacter) :   Dropping column(s) E of class(es) data.frame` when dtm is a SpatRaster

Comment: `ttops$E <- ttops$Z + Zdtm[[2]]`. `Zdtm` is a `data.frame`

Comment: thank you. this is the answer.